# Running NodeJS/Express projects on production server

Tags: node.js, express, dev-to-production

1 With different apps different website domain etc, NodeJS cannot go to production with `host:*some port other than 80*`, right? If I am wrong, how to deal with NodeJS apps with multiple website on the same machine? ( there is no `virtualhost` in NodeJS/Express server, isn't there?)

2 So the solution to go prod to me, only alternative is to use some proxy forwarding requests to the NodeJS/Express `server IP:port`, isn't it? If yes and if it is a different server ( proxy and NodeJS), what does express to start and listen to? (Say, `server.listen('port', '0.0.0.0')` or `server.listen('port', '::')`?

3 Any other alternatives to go production with NodeJS/Express projects?

Answer (score 0):

You can use 80 but with sudo. However, it's not recommended.

You're right you need a proxy (nginx, haproxy, etc..) to sit in front of your Node.js app in order to use port 80.

I think you can omit `host` from `server.listen` so it will accept connection from `::`.

Answer (score 0):

[NGINX](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/) is the best option to do, what you expect and see the NGINX documentation in official web site.